# Get image width

Tags: php, image

I'm normally using `getimagesize` to get image width. but sometime it doesn't return anything.

For example :

```
getimagesize('images/image num 1.jpg');
```

So is there any other function that can return image width.

Comment: Are you sure it's a valid image?

Comment: @Maerlyn Yes, all my image are valid.

Comment: Try replacing %20 for space characters.

Answer (score 0):

If you use image name like this in your question, there is a problem.you must remove the white spaces.

In **JAVA**, i've used this

(I already know the file's type)

```
Random generator = new Random();
int r = generator.nextInt(100000);
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
//rename file         
file.setFileName((now.getTimeInMillis() + r)+"."+type);
photo_name = file.getFileName();
//...
uploadphoto(photo_name);
```

There are a lot of relevant php methods that produce random names,number etc.For example

```
$photo_name = (date("Y-m-d H:i:s") . $users_ip);
```

Comment: That the problem.. all my image in my website are uploaded by users.

Comment: hmmm,then the problem is the filenames, not the dir.ok, then I' suggest that you give a name to these images when users upload them. I'd use random names for example (fgsadsf34345.png) and remember the relation between user and image (for example using a db)

Comment: or do a simple validation of the filename before the request is finished... If the filename has spaces, change them out for underscores before any db entries are added and directly after they've been uploaded...